# An appropriate phrase for sameness in politics

Tags: phrase-requests

The sentence that I am writing is

**Such a presumption assumes [sameness] in political dynamics across countries which is certainly not true.**

The intended meaning is, to point out the person's argument is derived from the notion that politics in countries are more or less same, so laws in one country are suitable for another.

However, the phrase "sameness in political dynamics" does not seem sensible. Seeming is certainly subjective and thus I don't really have evidence to demonstrate why it is insensible. So please let me know if it goes with the context, and if it doesn't what a better alternative could be?

Comment: "homegeneity", "uniformity", various other synonyms here http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/sameness

Comment: With respect to justifying applying the same reasoning to different situations, *congruence* also works. *Such a presumption assumes congruent political dynamics across countries which is certainly not true.*

Answer (score 1):

The word I would use in that sentence would be either ***universality***, or ***uniformity***..

Answer (score 0):

You're talking about political dynamics. The dynamics assume some direction or vector. Maybe some word meaning "the same direction" would be appropriate? For instance - unipolarity.
The second way is to think of politics as the sum of opinions of different people with the intention to bring it into action. Think of something that means the same opinion, like conformity.
The third way is to find some appropriate synonym for homogeneity.
Disclaimer: I am not English speaker.